# Iframe on my website blocking Facebook login

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I am integrating a facebook login on a website, when I click on the login button, everything works perfect.

The problem is that I have different iframe on the website and when I open a iframe, and then I click on the Facebook button, no longer performs the login and must click 2 times for the login is successful. The first time, sent me and I returned to facebook

mydomain.com/?code=AQBBUikowvG3plEzLmvOXUmentATkPf8n6TQzdVxNWOAZ5jD-&state=21c4e7aa#*=*

then I have to click again and the login is done successfully.

I'm using this library to connect with facebook [github.com/appleboy/codeigniter-facebook-php-sdk-v4](http://www.github.com/appleboy/codeigniter-facebook-php-sdk-v4)

Why I can not perform my login after opening an iframe?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to the FB login dialog _within_ the iframe? That is not possible; for security reasons it must always be called within the top window instance.

Comment: No, I have iframes on my page, but I have facebook login on the top window.

Comment: FB login dialog will redirect back to your page in the top window as well – so you will have to handle the `code` parameter that gets passed via URL there. Are you doing that?

Comment: you're right, I had a call to the API of facebook in the parent page and the iframe, the iframe to remove everything worked properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @CBroe, you're right, I had a call to the API of facebook in the parent page and the iframe, the iframe to remove everything worked properly.